# Все варианты перестановок элементов массива

Tags: c++

Есть массив букв *АБВГД*. Необходимо найти все варианты перестановок, т.е. *АБ*, *АВ*, *АБВ*, *АВДГ*, *АБВГД*, от двух и до пяти (в данном случае) символов.

Пробовал использовать `std::next_permutation`, однако это не совсем то, что требуется, так как при, например, трех символах он выводит только трехсимвольные комбинации.

Я это решил при выводе, но возникла новая проблема. Как только в массиве появляются две звездочки (что тоже необходимо по условиям задачи), `std::next_permutation` перестает работать. В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

```
int Fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 2 || n == 1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return n * Fact(n - 1);
    }
}

void PrintC(char*arr, int len, int ind)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    cout << '\t';
    for (int i = 2; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (len > 1 && ind % Fact(len - i) == 0)
        {
            PrintC(arr, len - 1, ind);
        }
    }
}

int len = 3;
char* arr = new char[len + 1];
cin.getline(arr, len + 1);
sort(&arr[0], &arr[len]);
int ind = 1;
do
{
    cout << ind << endl << endl;
    PrintC(arr, len, ind);
    cout << endl;
    ind++;

}
while (next_permutation(&arr[0], &arr[len]));
_getch();
return;
```

Comment: Задача больше походит на построение мощного множества(power set), чем на перестановки. `next_permutation` занимается именно, что перестановками.

Comment: Т.е. возможно стоит найти все подмножества с определенным количеством элементов и потом переставлять элементы в них?


В любом случае, а в чем проблема с next_permutation? Скажем так, так и должно быть или это я где-то ошибся?

Comment: Ну мне полностью Ваше задание не ясно, но похоже на то, что Вам нужны *размещения*, а не перестановки. Это, в целом, решается построением мощного множества в котором, затем, уже используются перестановки на каждом подмножестве, которое содержит больше одного эелемента. С `next_permutation` никаких проблем нет, просто эта функция предназначена для перестановок, а не для размещений.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать битовую маску [0,0,1], [0,1,1], [1,1,1] (в данном случае,для трех элементов, количество единиц - количество выводимых элементов). Пока next_permutation => проходим по массиву и выводим элементы, соответствующие единице.

Из минусов, оверхед по памяти.